# C# Outlook addin - Display form on ItemSend

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm new to developing addins in C# so apologies if this is a simple question.

Basically i'm trying to create a addin where once a user clicks send it opens a form that the user can use to select the message classification.

I've set up the form but i'm having difficulty calling the form when the item is sent.

What i've got so far is:

```
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ItemSend += new 
        Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(FormRegion1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thank you for your time in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
}

void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, worked great. I've got the form woking now but I'm having difficulty with the sending of the email once i've applied conditions. i.e. the form opens when the message is sent and I select the classification i want but I'm unsure how to send it after that. any advice?

Comment: You need to show a dialog window to stop the sending process (see `ShowDialog`). As soon as the form is closed the message can be sent without preventing Outlook from doing that.